# Javascript Code to show div boxes not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have this piece of Javascript Code that works great on Chrome and Internet Explorer but I can't get it to work in Firefox

```
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function aufklappen(id, arr) {


    $('.3').attr("src", "images/leftarrow.png");

    var style = $("div[id='" + id + "']").attr("style");

    $('.2').hide();

    if (style == "display: none;") {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        elem.style.display = "block";
        $("#" + arr).attr("src", "images/downarrow.png");
    } else {

        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        elem.style.display = "none";
        $("#" + arr).attr("src", "images/leftarrow.png");
    }
}
    </script>
```

I have a code getting data out of a mysql database displaying some basic data.
What I am trying to do is to show a hidden div box, which contains more details, when I click on an image. In addition I want to change this picture to show an arrow that's pointing down.
If someone clicks on one of these images I first want to hide all divs so that there is only one hidden div box shown at a time.
Every image has `class="3"` and every hidden div box `class="2"`. The ID's are created dynamically so I can show the div box I want.
I call the function with this code:

```
<a onclick='aufklappen("<? echo $flightnum;?>2", "<? echo $flightnum;?>arr")'><img class="3" id="<? echo $flightnum;?>arr" src="images/leftarrow.png" /></a>
```

Comment: You should use vanilla JS or jQuery instead of mixing & matching the two.

Comment: Why are you referencing two jQuery libraries? The uncompressed one and the minimized one, both on the same page?

Comment: Also, never try to read the `style` attribute. It's a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd struggle to answer without a demo to work through.  However, I can provide you with a couple of pointers and see what comes of it.

a. I can see that you've used three different techniques of selecting by Id.  For consistency, choose one.

```
1. var style = $("div[id='" + id +"']").attr("style");

2. var elem = document.getElementById(id);

3. $("#" + arr).attr("src","images/downarrow.png");
```

b. Replace this

```
var style = $("div[id='" + id +"']").attr("style");
```

with

```
var style = $("div[id='" + id +"']").css("display");
```

then change this

```
if (style == "display: none;")
```

to

```
if (style === "none")
```

See how you get on.

Comment: That one worked, thanks! I tried to change a as well and it worked for me to change `var style = $("div[id='" + id +"']").attr("style");` to `var style = $("#" + id).css("display");`but I could find a way to use this method for `var elem = document.getElementById(id);`. `var elem = $("#" + id)` didn't work.